# How do I set @ViewChild('anchor_name') after html element with anchor changed in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, anchor, viewchild

I get an item with GET request then on subscribe set the item_id. In html I make div with anchor id="{{this.item_id}}". After it I get the error:

```
FeedComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

I understand that when constructor checks the html elements this exactly element with this anchor isn't exist. But I can't figure out how do I set unchor with @ViewChild on subscribe of GET request?

There is the component:

```
export class MyClass {
     @ViewChild('10') private myScrollContainer: ElementRef;

     item_id = 0;

     constructor (scrollChecker: ScrollChecker) {
         this.getItem();
     }

     getItem(){
        // get request there
        .subscribe((p) => {
            this.item_id = p.id;
        });
     }

     doScrollToItem(){
        this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0,this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.offsetTop]);
     }
}
```

The html:

```
<div *ngIf="item_id" id="{{item_id}}"></div>
```

Comment: Because the element is not immediately rendered, you could first use `@ViewChild(nameOfSelector, { static: false })`, then, in your html you could to this: `<app-comp *ngIf="item_id !== null" #nameOfSelector>`

Comment: The error you are getting has nothing to do with your html, you must be calling doScrollToItem somewhere. With your html, worst case would give you 0 then would update to whatever id is

Answer (score 0):

Call your scroll inside a setter if it needs to be called once: If you want to set the Id, call your getItem from inside the setter. That way, _myContainer is going to be setted when the subscribe is called

```
const _myContainer: ElementRef

@ViewChild('10') set myScrollContainer(element: ElementRef) {
    if(element && element.nativeElement) {
        _myContainer = element;
        this.getItem()
    }
}

getItem(){
    // get request there
    .subscribe((p) => {
        this.item_id = p.id;
        //set your id using angular renderer2
        this.renderer.setAttribute(this._myContainer, 'id', p.id)
        });
     }

constructor (scrollChecker: ScrollChecker, private renderer: Renderer2) {
     }
```

otherwise just check if this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement is undefined before scrolling inside doScrollToItem():

```
    doScrollToItem(){
        if(this.myScrollContainer && this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement) { 
            this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0,this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.offsetTop]);
        }
    );
```

Comment: I added *ngIf="item_id" to this div. I still can't understand how to set @ViewChild('10') set myScrollContainer... inside getItem(){subscribe...}. Because befor answer from request from getItem() this html element is not existed.

Comment: Updated to match what you want

Comment: I could be wrong about the setAttribute parameter but it should be close.